# Select row of unbound datagridview populated by query

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a query that populates a DGV that looks like

```
private void textBox6_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataClasses3DataContext db = new DataClasses3DataContext();

        int matchedAdd = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                          where c.HOUSE_NO.Contains(textBox1.Text) && c.Direction.Contains(textBox2.Text) && c.street.Contains(textBox3.Text) && c.SUFF.Contains(textBox4.Text)
                          select c.ID).SingleOrDefault();

        var before = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                      where c.ID < matchedAdd
                      orderby c.PARCEL descending
                      select c).Take(6);

        var after = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                     where c.ID > matchedAdd
                     orderby c.PARCEL
                     select c).Take(6);

        var endResult = before.Concat(after);

        dgvBRT.DataSource = endResult;

    }
```

I need to be able to select a row and open BRTDetail from the DGV after its populated by that query.  This is the first time I have had to use an unbound grid.  The code I normally use is below.  Obviously it doesn't work since BRTDataSet is irrelevant at that point.  How do I select a row in this case?

```
        private void dgvBRT_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRowView;
        BRTDataSet.propRow SelectedRow;

        SelectedRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)propBindingSource.Current;
        SelectedRow = (BRTDataSet.propRow)SelectedRowView.Row;

        frmBRTDetail BRTDetail = new frmBRTDetail(this);
        BRTDetail.LoadBRTNumberKey(SelectedRow.PARCEL, null);
        BRTDetail.LoadBldgKey(SelectedRow.BLDG_CD, null);
        BRTDetail.Show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out.  This is how I did it.

```
private void dgvBRT_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

         if (dgvBRT.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
             int selectedrowindex = dgvBRT.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

             DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgvBRT.Rows[selectedrowindex];

             string BRTNumber = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["BRTNumber"].Value);  
             // Open selected row

              frmBRTDetail BRTDetail = new frmBRTDetail(this);
              BRTDetail.LoadBRTNumberKey(BRTNumber, null);
              BRTDetail.Show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How bout this create an template field named something :

```
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="link_button" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClick="link_button_Click"> </asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Then in your code behind for the click event you do this :

```
 protected void link_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

       // this selects your row and you can access the controls of your grid. 


   }
```

Comment: The ItemTemplate code is for webforms correct?  This is a winform application.

Comment: I didn't see it was a winform. I think the code behind logic would still work. you just may need to tweak the syntax.